# Rails view Rspec tests expectations not met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I think Rspec view tests are messing up because the links that the tests are looking for are not part of the actual view, but of the application layout header.

For example, I have the following Rspec code:

```
  describe 'signups/new.html.erb' do

  before :each do
    render template: "signups/new", layout: "layouts/application"
  end

  it 'displays link to request pages not signup page' do
    rendered.should have_link("Make a new request", href: new_request_path)
    rendered.should_not have_link("Add me to the mailing list", href: new_signup_path)
  end
```

The error that I'm getting is that the link "Add me to the mailing list" has been found. Yet I assure you, in the local server this is not the case.

What's happening in the view is below (again this is all from the layouts/application file, NOT from signups/new):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_path %>">Home</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= new_request_path %>">Make a new request</a>
      <% if current_page?(new_signup_path) == false %>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= new_signup_path %>">Add me to the mailing list</a>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Basically it's an If/Then stating that when you're in the signup page, do not show a link to send users to the signup page. Yet the Rspec is indicating that this link is present. Any thoughts on why?

I'm thinking somehow the test is not interpolating the if/then statement, but not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

put a `puts page.body` right before the line `rendered.should have_link("Make a new request", href: new_request_path)` I don't think your spec is even on the page.

like so

```
it 'displays link to request pages not signup page' do
  puts page.body
  rendered.should have_link("Make a new request", href: new_request_path)
  rendered.should_not have_link("Add me to the mailing list", href: new_signup_path)
end
```

EDIT:

re-read the question, my previous advice is not all that useful, although `puts page.body` is a nice thing to help with tests.  I think perhaps it's because you are rendering signup/new, but that is not the path, so it is not the "current page". Maybe try a redirect_to instead.

Try a `visit new_signups_path` or whatever your path is (check with `rake routes` where I had the `puts.page.body`. You can probably(I think, but it depends on your other tests) get rid of the before :each

Comment: Hmm, what does that do? Right now I tried it and it's throwing another error for wrong number of arguments   '  1) signups/new.html.erb displays link to request pages not signup page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mputs page.body rendered.should have_link("Make
 a new request", href: new_request_path)←[0m
     ←[31mArgumentError←[0m:
       ←[31mwrong number of arguments (1 for 0)←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/views/signups/new.html.erb_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in
 <top (required)>'←[0m'

Comment: it should be on its own line.  It will put the html of the page it is on.

Comment: Of course silly me. Unfortunately though, I'm still getting the same error: '  1) signups/new.html.erb displays link to request pages not signup page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mrendered.should_not have_link("Add me to the m
ailing list", href: new_signup_path)←[0m
     ←[31mCapybara::ExpectationNotMet←[0m:
       ←[31mexpected not to find link "Add me to the mailing list", found 1 matc
h: "Add me to the mailing list"←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/views/signups/new.html.erb_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in
 <top (required)>'←[0m

Comment: now that I re read the question, I think perhaps its because you are rendering signup/new, but that is not the path, so it is not the "current page".  Maybe try a redirect_to instead

Comment: Interesting, I'm reading the docs, and I'm not sure redirect_to can be written without a "something should" in front of it. But in this case, I want just the page. Thoughts?

Comment: Try a `visit new_signups_path` or whatever your path is (check with `rake routes` where I had the `puts.page.body`. You can probably(I think, but it depends on your other tests) get rid of the before :each

Comment: Hmm... no change unfortunately.

Comment: what is the output of a `puts page.url` in the test?

Comment: Visit new_signup_path, puts page.body, and doing nothing (my original question) have the same error that I wrote in a previous comment:  '1) signups/new.html.erb displays link to request pages not signup page ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mrendered.should_not have_link("Add me to the m ailing list", href: new_signup_path)←[0m ←[31mCapybara::ExpectationNotMet←[0m: ←[31mexpected not to find link "Add me to the mailing list", found 1 matc h: "Add me to the mailing list"←[0m ←[36m # ./spec/views/signups/new.html.erb_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

Comment: There is no output of the page though?

Comment: oh you mean on local server, the output looks fine, it's exactly as the test states

Comment: but the `puts page.body` should output the current(the one your test is on) page's html while you are running your tests, in the terminal.  It wont be where if shows the error of your test, but when the test was actually run.  Also check what your routes say, with `rake routes`.

Comment: oh interesting... may be a bigger problem then because my terminal doesn't change its output at all after adding puts page.body

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your test, you need to use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to navigate to the signup page.

For example, if your signup route is /signup, you would call

```
visit '/signup'
```

in your before each block.

Comment: What I did was replace the render template/layout with visit '/signups/new' which is the path in rake routes, and then all of my tests failed =/